# How to handle Antiforgerytoken with browsers that have disabled cookies and ASP.NET

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, antiforgerytoken

I've been trying to search for an alternative for browsers that have disabled cookies in their browser and forms that require the antiforgerytoken for validation.  How should a case like this be handled?

Any suggestions or alternatives to preventing CSRF in ASP.Net MVC forms would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own CUSTOM ANTIFORGERYTOKEN FILTER for more details
check the links...

http://forums.asp.net/t/1938599.aspx 
http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/securing_all_forms_using_antiforgerytoken

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of alternatives to using AntiForgeryTokens stored in session as part of the Synchroniser Token Pattern. One method gaining traction is the [Encrypted Token Pattern](http://insidethecpu.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/encrypted-token-pattern/), implemented by a Framework called ARMOR. The premise here is that you need neither Session nor cookies in order to maintain CSRF protection in a stateless manner, which won't be interrupted by browser settings, particularly the disabling of cookies.